# extract some info from a complete sentance using preg_match

Tags: preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to extract specific info using preg_match in php. Is there any idea?

```
sample text = 2xMUA Matte Lipstick - Totally Nude[300]=[600]
```

here i want to

```
product_name = MUA Matte Lipstick - Totally Nude
product_qty = 2
product_price = 300
product_subtotal = 600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture your values in (named) [captured groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

Try it like this:

[`(?<qty>\d+)x(?<name>[^[]+)\[(?<price>[^]]+)\]=\[(?<subtotal>[^]]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/zXW0YF/1)

That would match:

```
(?<qty>      # Named captured group qty
  \d+        # One or more digits
)            # Close group
x            # Match x
(?<name>     # Named captured group name
  [^[]+      # Match not [ one or more times
)            # Close group
\[           # Match [
(?<price>    # Named captured group price
  [^]]+      # Match not ] one or more times
)            # Close group
\]=\[        # Match ]=[
(?<subtotal> # Named captured group subtotal
  [^]]+      # # Match not ] one or more times
)            # Close group
\]           # Match ]
```

[Demo php](https://3v4l.org/hKfSO)

Or without named captured groups:

[`(\d+)x([^[]+)\[([^]]+)\]=\[([^]]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/zXW0YF/2)